# restrict input values using check constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to restrict the input values for column id where values which are between 2 and 5 only those will be allowed to be inserted in the id column,to do so I'm using check constraint but it's not working at all.In the following I'm inserting three rows where 2nd and 3rd rows are not satisfying the check condition but still they are getting inserted.

How can I restrict those values?I'm using `mysql 5.6` and `InnoDB` database engine.

```
start transaction;

drop table if exists company ;

create table company(

   id int check(id between 2 and 5),

   name varchar(20));

insert into company(id,name) values(2,'Ron'),(6,'Queen'),(1,'Loren');

commit;

rollback;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHOCK HORROR! Mysql *ignores* check constraints!

Mysql "[supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)" check constraints only so far as allowing them in create table statements, but only for *compatibility* with schemas exported from other databases - once defined they are totally ignored.

Use a trigger to enforce such constraints.